# How to write data immediatly to socket without using flush and waitFOrBytesWritten with QTCPSocket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

In my application, While writing to socket the data is not written immediately. 
But if i use the flush() or waitForByteWritten(msec) then it get written. 
But here the only problem with flush() and waitforByteWritten() is its creating a performance bottleneck.

If i use it then performance is not so good. But if i doesn't use flush()/waitforBytesWritten() then data itself doesn't transfer immediately.

Is there any flag or something so that data can be written as the data is written to buffer.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: if you are `write()`ing small chunks of data within small time intervals, maybe you should disable [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), using [`tcpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption)

Comment: Hint: return to the event loop *as soon as possible*!

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking the event loop. Don't do that. The code that writes to the socket should return as soon as it's done.